# Paypal smart buttons credit card error management

Tags: paypal

I'm using paypal smart buttons sdk to fullfill paypal payment by credit card or paypal balance. the problem is for sandbox negative testing i was unable to test bad credit card cases because of lack of documentation (or may be it's me who didn't search enough).
so i decided to test in a production like environment with my production paypal business account and intentionally put a bad credit card secret .
The problem is when calling order.capture() function paypal raises a lot of errors but i'm unable to catch them and manage them correctly
here is my calling code :

```
onApprove: async (data: any, actions: any) => {

          const order = await actions.order;
          this.logger.log(order);
          try {
            order.capture().then((details: any) => {
              this.logger.log('[PAYPAL onApprove : ]' + details);
              const payPalCreateOrderResponse: PayPalCreateOrderResponse = new PayPalCreateOrderResponse();
              payPalCreateOrderResponse.details = details;
              this.checkOutEventsStore.paymentDetails = payPalCreateOrderResponse;


            });
          } catch (e) {
            this.managePaypalError(params, e);
            this.logger.error('====> Paypal Order Capture ERROR ' + e);
          }
        }
```

the errors i see in console :

```
POST https://www.paypal.com/smart/api/order/order_id_replaced/capture 500
(anonyme) @ buttons?
(anonyme) @ js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR&locale=fr_FR&debug=true:4841
ZalgoPromise.try @ js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR&locale=fr_FR&debug=true:770
(anonyme) @ js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR&locale=fr_FR&debug=true:4834
(anonyme) @ js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&currency=EUR&locale=fr_FR&debug=true:4851

######## a lot of stack ommited
Error: Api: /smart/api/order/order_id_replaced/capture returned status code: 500 (Corr ID: f2967533987cc)

{"ack":"error","message":"Unhandled api error","meta":{"calc":"f2967533987cc","rlog":"rZJvnqaaQhLn%2FnmWT8cSUueWscmrtUHe5Y1Bd%2FeqyvyOTq66rSXAcgw%2BjwUfLWoirTjSF3Dcz2NbXl4NQOgVH84XX3DSygFN_17c9d7d88e6"},"server":"HR8xYFSZUP13jAt-X87VBJ7lq_LqwktwVsmzzP_zQqInVub3-ylXm8UuExvdz-SWJ0NH49XoaSL2hE_9LzQo_5B-X0COwFFVi2Z4c-cTCQBGoBSZtkefMbHWojX3rQ4-qLZIYQefq6OE7funNI8ZnGZUi9YpufYlG9X1qx89zj0l4LERQ9wesnqMpT59y3GbjqsfOGbGf7uasTCGOz6f58ZNMbdNVYrz1h5gc3sZbk-LhH5ks1k1DqJV7UPsxus1QBII26hjpRQbnFr6VLiyCW"}
```

and the most important , in the network api calls i can see clearly for :
https://www.paypal.com/smart/api/order/order_id_replaced/capture api call
a good json result for the error :

```
{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"issue":"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","description":"The instrument presented  was either declined by the processor or bank, or it can't be used for this payment."}],"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"f569254a2e9c8","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=token_replaced","rel":"redirect","method":"GET"}]}
```

So the question is how to manage this error correctly by using the js api.

Thank you for your Help .
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

> when calling order.capture() function paypal raises a lot of errors but I'm unable to catch them and manage them correctly

When capturing on the client side with `.capture()` , if the capture is declined PayPal will automatically offer the payer the ability to try again, likely falling back to a modal window.  No error handling by you is necessary, required, nor possible.

If you were capturing on the server side (which you are not doing), there is sample error handling code in [this demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server).

Comment: thank you for your reply,  "likely falling back to a modal window
",  this is what i want to do but where , is there a possibility to do it like this : order.capture().then(....).error( err => {}) , i can not find an example  in the api documentation

Comment: It's automatic.

Comment: The actual behavior , paypal is closing the payment dialog without any message and showing the loaded buttons  page for another retry , but the user is unable to know if the payment is OK or not , not even me , this why error handling is necessary , so i can inform client that his payment is declined

Comment: INSTRUMENT_DECLINED is handled automatically. You appear to be having some other problem.

Comment: For generic, 500-type errors (not applicable to an INSTRUMENT_DECLINED) , you can implement an onError callback to show a generic message.  See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/#onerror